# Return start and end of next interval depending on current time

Tags: python, datetime, intervals, python-3.8

I'm searching for a way to get the start and the end datetime of a specific interval, which is following after the ongoing inerval of the same length. The intervals always starts at the first minute and second of an hour and `60 mod interval` is always 0 (so the intervals always fit in an 60 Minute timespan like 1m,3m,5m,15m,30m).

For a 15 minute interval possible datetime would be for example:

```
...
interval_start="2021-04-02 09:00:00", interval_end="2021-04-02 09:14:59"
interval_start="2021-04-02 09:15:00", interval_end="2021-04-02 09:29:59"
interval_start="2021-04-02 09:30:00", interval_end="2021-04-02 09:44:59"
interval_start="2021-04-02 09:45:00", interval_end="2021-04-02 09:59:59"
interval_start="2021-04-02 10:00:00", interval_end="2021-04-02 10:14:59"
...
```

When I call the function with a current time of `2021-04-02 09:20:46`, the function should return the next following interval:

```
{ "interval_start": "2021-04-02 09:30:00", "interval_end"="2021-04-02 09:44:59"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
from math import ceil

def next_interval(t, interval):
    start_hr = t.hour
    mins_float = t.minute + t.second/60
    start_min = ceil(mins_float/interval)*interval
    
    start = t.replace(second=0, millisecond=0, microsecond=0, minute=start_min, hour=start_hr)
    end = start + dt.timedelta(minutes=interval)

    return {'interval_start': start, 'interval_end': end}
```

The edge cases (e.g. what to do if the intervals don't evenly divide into 60 minutes) and formatting I'll leave to you, but hope this helps get you started.